# FATAL Error: Unable to complete saved object migrations for the [.kibana] index: Unable to complete the INIT step after 15 attempts, terminating

Tags: elasticsearch, search, server, kibana, ubuntu-18.04

I have an error in running  kibana.
i am running this code 'journalctl -fu kibana.service' and show this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApZOL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome! This question needs a lot more detail. E.g., details like where and how you're running this service, the version, where and you're running Elasticsearch, more of the error traceback.